# $E'$ is closed, where $E'$ is the set of limit points of $E$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$E'$ is the set of all limit points of $E$.

Proving $E'$ is closed:

---

> $E$ is finite

1) If $E$ is finite, then $E$ has no limit points and hence $E'=\emptyset$ and hence $E'$ is closed.

---

> What if $E$ is infinite?

If $x\in E'$ then $x$ is a limit point of $E$.

Proof

Assume $x\in E'$ and $x$ is not a limit point of $E$.

---

And above I am lost, how do I prove $E'$ is closed? I know it has to be obviously(since it is literally defined as a set of limit points...).

---

Source: Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, Page 43, question 6.

Comment: I believe this is from Rudin, yes? In any case, it is always good practice to disclose the source. You should also declare which definitions you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for metric spaces:

Just show that $\complement E'$ is open. If $y \notin E'$, then there must be an $r>0$ such that $B(y,r)$ does not contain any element of $E$ (since $y$ is not a limit point).

Now show that $B(y,r)$ cannot contain any element of $E'$

Comment: Should your $E$ up there be $(E')^c$ [or as you have written $\complement E'$]? Or it is fine since $E\subset (E')^c = X/E'$? Where $X$ is the universe

Comment: No, it is $X \setminus E'$. If this set is open, then you are done. Just draw a picture: If $B(y,r)$ contains an element of $E'$, then this would be a limit point, so there is some Element $e$ of $E$ near $y$

Comment: Thank you, yes I asked a second question to clarify this after writing that comment, and then after that was answered I understood your answer completely and accepted it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\{L_i\}$ has limit $L$, and the sequence $a_{ij}$ (as $j$ varies) has limit $L_i$ for all $i$.
Take a sequence of open sets $B_i$ whose limit is $L$, and assume $B_{i+1}\subset B_i$.
Take a subset of the sequences, so that now $L_i\in B_i$.
Let $C_i$ be an open set with $L_i\in C_i\subset B_i$.
Take one element from each sequence $a_{ik_i}$ so that $a_{ik_i}\in C_i$.
Then $a_{ik_i}\in B_i$, and the sequence $b_i=a_{ik_i}$ tends to $L$.

Comment: I thought of this at first as well, but Rudin uses punctured neighborhoods for limit points. So we need a slight adjustment for this proof I think.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Blah's outline, here is a proof directly from the definition of a limit point:

Let $p\in E''$. Then by definition $\forall\epsilon,\exists q\in B_\epsilon (p)\cap E'\setminus\{p\}$. Let $\epsilon>0$ and take a limit point $q\in B_\epsilon (p)\setminus\{p\}$. Reciting the definition of a limit point (of $E$ this time), we have that $\forall\epsilon',\exists r\in B_{\epsilon'} (q)\cap E\setminus\{q\}$.

I leave it to you to pick $\epsilon'$ so that it is guaranteed that we can find an $r\in E$ for which $r\in B_\epsilon(p)\setminus\{p\}$ holds.

Hint: Draw a picture.