# $y \notin E'\implies \exists r\gt 0|B(y,r)$ does not contain any elements of $E$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

(For metric spaces in Rudin, related to this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1161399/214109))

Let $E'$ denote the set of all limit points of $E$.

> If $y \notin E'$, then there must be an $r\gt 0$ such that $B(y,r)$ does not contain any element of $E$

How do I prove this?

---

Definitions:

A point $p$ is a limit point of the set $E$ if every neighbourhood of $p$ contains a point $q\ne p$ such that $q\in E$

Comment: How does Rudin define limit points?

Comment: @Moya A point $p$ is a limit point of the set $E$ if every neighbourhood of $p$ contains a point $q\ne p$ such that $q\in E$

Comment: @Moya So by definition(which I am not comfortable with yet I suppose), we must have some neighbourhood(since it isn't a limit point) such that there is a point also in $(E')^C$

Comment: So if $y\not\in E'$, then there is a neighborhood $N$ such that $y\in N$ and $N\cap E=\emptyset$. Now...

Comment: @Moya Oh yes I see, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If $y \notin E'$, then there must be an $r\gt 0$ such that $B(y,r)$ does not contain any element of $E$

Proof:

$y$ is not a limit point, and hence we fail to meet the criteria:

- A point $p$ is a limit point of the set $E$ if every neighbourhood of $y$ contains a point $q\ne y$ such that $q\in E$

and hence there is some neighborhood of $y\in (E')^c$ that contains no point $q\ne y$ such that $q\in (E')^c$

> And since $E\subset (E')^c = X/E'$ where $X$ is the universe, the conjecture is proven. $\blacksquare$

Comment: The notation is a bit weird, but it's the right idea.

Comment: @Moya Would you use $\complement E'$ for complement of $E'$? and something else for the set of limit points of $E$?

Comment: Really the statmeent is this: $y\in (E')^c$ means there is $N$ a neighborhood such that $y\in N$ and $N\cap E=\emptyset$. Thus $y\in N\subset E^c$. So there is $r>0$ such that $y\in B(y,r)\subset N\subset E^c$, so $B(y,r)\cap E=\emptyset$.

Comment: @Moya Thanks :).